# Min-width 0 doesn't work for buttons

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-animate

I wish to replace one button with another with a smooth animation and without changing the height of the element, as I'll have other buttons underneath them that I don't want to move (so I don't think that I can use .hide and .show and I want a right to left replacement anyway). I'm open to solutions using other technology, but note that I want this to run in all modern browsers on PC, Android and iOS.

I thought that I'd use JQuery ".animate". However when I set up the code sample below and click the button it doesn't shrink away to nothing (despite my setting min-width).

If this can't be fixed it will rather put a crimp in my special effect and overly complicate working around it (I'd have a jerk at the end when the first button, having reached non-zero minimum size, just vanishes and the other one is jumped to full size).

In the final version there would be another button after the first that would be expanded from 0px at the same time, but I presume (until told differently) that resolving the script below will also lead to how to start at 0px width.

Please help. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("button").animate({width:'0px'});
  });
});
</script> 
<style>
button {
min-width:0px;
height: 22px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<button>Start Animation</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is because the button also has a padding and a border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively you can directly add the CSS property on your code. have a look at **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yicaruca/1/edit)**.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("button").animate({width:'0px', padding:'0', border:'0'});
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi. While this resolves the literal problem I was having quite nicely, thanks, please see this follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841556/how-to-get-to-default-appearance

Answer (score 0):

add  below css to button

```
 display:inline-block;
 padding:0px;
 border:0px;
```

Comment: Can you explain why that is?

Comment: @putvande `button` element have some padding and by default `1px border`, this is the reason by setting the `width:0` you still see the button unless you reset them to `0`. or you might be add a CSS reset property.