# How to get to default appearance

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-animate

[This is a follow up to a problem posted earlier. Click here to open it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840150/min-width-0-doesnt-work-for-buttons)

I now have the following code, but I can't get the second button that appears to adopt the default border and padding. Please help. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#b1").animate({width:'0px', padding:'0', border:'0'}, { duration: 1000, queue: false });
    $("#b2").animate({width:'200px', padding:"", border:""}, { duration: 1000, queue: false });
  });
});
</script> 
<style>
button {
min-width:0px;
height: 22px;
width: 200px;
}

#b2 {
width: 0px;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
}


</style>
</head>

<body>
<button id="b1">Start Animation</button><button id="b2">Animation Done</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pretty cool, except that opaque or not, it's still taking up some space after the animation :(

Comment: After it's done the new button is further to the right than the original, presumably because the original is still taking up some space.

Comment: I'm getting closer to a solution by starting with display: none for b2 and using .show before the animation. However, as b1 shrinks the text wraps and the button drops. In another language I would control this by setting baselineAligned to false, but I don't know how to deal with it here.

Comment: Good to know you have solved your problem mate. I am removing the earlier comments to reduce noise :)

Comment: Its' still not perfect. I didn't notice that b2 is too fat initially, which could result in some issues re the rest of the page being moved as the combined width of the two buttons will be fatter than it should be.

Comment: Wat “default border and padding”? If you mean browser defaults, there is no way to get back to them if you have made some settings that override them.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can solve like below

css code:

```
button {
min-width:0px;
height: 22px;
width: 200px;
}

#b2 {
width: 0px; display:none;
}
```

jquery code:

```
 $("button").click(function(){
     $("#b1").animate({width:'0px',padding:'0px'}, 1000,function(){$('#b1').hide();});
     $("#b2").css('display','inline-block').animate({width:'200px'}, { duration: 1000, queue: false });
  });
```

you can see the result here ---> http://jsfiddle.net/Junkie/4c9g3/